# What's the expectation of the function given by $|X_1|$ when $X=(X_1 \dots X_d) \sim Unif(S^{d-1}(r))$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Let $X=(X_1 \dots X_d) \sim Unif(r S^{d-1} \equiv S^{d-1}(r) ).$ I'd like to know what's the expectation of $|X_1|,$ i.e. what's the integral:

$$ \frac{1}{vol(S^{d-1}(r))} \int_{S^{d-1}(r)} |x_1| d vol_{S^{d-1}(r)}? $$

I think my problem is with the **complicated volume form in high dimensional spheres**, and **reducing the polar coordinates to cartesian co-ordinates for integration**. This is where I need a bit of help, unless there's *more slick way using symmetry e*tc.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @Aryadeva Thanks a lot - I appreciate it :) I hope my clarification of the point of getting stuck was useful.

Comment: I don't know if it leads anywhere, but you may note that, by symmetry, $\mathbb{E}|X_1|=\frac{1}{d} \mathbb{E}\sum_{j=1}^d |X_j|$ and that, by scaling, $r^{-(d-1)}\int_{S^{d-1}(r)}\frac{|x_1|}{r}\textrm{d}\sigma_r$ is a constant function of $r$. This allows you to note that $\int_{S^{d-1}(1)}\|x\|_1\textrm{d}\sigma_1=\int_0^1 r^{-(d-1)}\int_{S^{d-1}(r)}\frac{\|x\|_1}{r}\textrm{d}\sigma_r\textrm{d}r=\int_{B(0,1)} \frac{\|x\|_1}{\|x\|_2}\textrm{d}x,$ where $\sigma$ denotes surface measure (or volume form if you prefer) and $\|\cdot\|_p$ denotes the $p$-norm on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Answer (score 0):

**Too long for a comment.**

I am far from an expert, but would this approach work? If you sum up all the $d Vol(S^{d-1}(r))$ pieces where $X_1 \in [x_1, x_1 + d x_1]$, the total $(d-1)$-dimensional volume would be:

$$d x_1 \times Vol(S^{d-2}(\sqrt{r^2 - x_1^2}))$$

So your integral becomes

$$\int_{-r}^r |x_1| \, Vol(S^{d-2}(\sqrt{r^2 - x_1^2}))\, d x_1$$

And you can plug in the known formula for $Vol(S^{d-2})$.  It may still be difficult to actually integrate, but at least it is now just an integration of one real variable $x_1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but unfortunately it doesn't work, as the for $d=3,$ the vol form on the sphere is a differential 2-form, whereas you wrote a differential 1-form.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was being careless in my first equation.  I have now tried to explain in a different way.  Does this make more sense now?